# Use value of variable in set statement in nunjucks macro

Tags: macros, nunjucks, eleventy

The following code works when I use collections.pages in the set statement of this nunjucks macro. collection_name is/prints collections.pages.  How do I use the value of collection_name in the last line/ set statment. Seems like this should be easy, but it doesn't seem to evaluate the value of collection_name in the set statement. Thanks!!!

```
        {% set collection_name = ["collections.", rel_content_sections_post_type] | join %}

    <p>collection_name is {{ collection_name }}</p>

        {% set related_item = collection_name | findInCollectionByPropertyAndValue('data.slug', item) %}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because when you're setting the related_item the collection_name is just a string therefore eleventy can't work with it. But I guess you can achieve what you want by using bracket notation to access the property of the eleventy's collection you want. You can do it in the same line you set the related_item. Like this:

```
{% set related_item = collections[rel_content_sections_post_type] | findInCollectionByPropertyAndValue('data.slug', item) %}
```

Then your findInCollectionByPropertyAndValue filter will receive the collection object and will be able to filter it and return whatever you want.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying with a solution! This does work and I should have thought of using the bracket notation. It was very smart of you to be able to see that solution especially in someone else's code.  

However, I feel like there should be a way to build a string up manually and have eleventy work with it. I expected there to be a way to take the collection_name variable and pass it to some kind of eval or toString() filter or syntax, or put extra curly braces around it, or something like that. It seems weird that you can't do something like that.